# Execute procedure asynchronously with task and wait VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await, sms, task

I am working on an application for sending bulk SMS, the code is this

My procedure

```
Private sub enviarsms()
    Dim dpmp As DatosParaMiProcedimiento
    Dim exito As Boolean = miCola.TryDequeue(dpmp)
    If exito Then
        ' Llamar al procedimiento
        miprocedimiento(dpmp.Telefono, dpmp.Mensaje)
    End If
End Sub

Sub miprocedimiento() 
    Serialport.Write(“ATZ0” & vbCr) 
    Serialport.WriteLine(“AT+CMGF=1” & vbCr) 
    Thread.Sleep(1000) 
    Serialport.Write(“AT+CMGS=” & Chr(34) & Telefono & Chr(34) & vbCr) 
    Serialport.Write(mensaje & Chr(26) & vbCr) 
    Thread.Sleep(1000) 
End Sub
```

and finally as I execute it

```
Private Async Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Await Task.Run(Sub()
                       enviarsms()
                   End Sub)
End Sub
```

The problem is that it does not send all the requested sms, of 600 it only sends 591 or less.

Comment: You don't even show the code sending the sms, so how can we help?

Comment: Sorry. Sub EnviarSMS()
Serialport.Write(“ATZ0” & vbCr)
            Serialport.WriteLine(“AT+CMGF=1” & vbCr) 
            Thread.Sleep(1000) 
            Serialport.Write(“AT+CMGS=” & Chr(34) & Telefono & Chr(34) & vbCr)  
            Serialport.Write(mensaje & Chr(26) & vbCr)
            Thread.Sleep(1000) 

End Sub

Comment: I added it to your question, but you already had a Sub with the same name

Comment: No exception handling. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming

Comment: I was wrong, instead of being Sub EnviarSMS (), it must be: Sub miprocedimiento ()

Comment: But you call that with arguments `miprocedimiento(dpmp.Telefono, dpmp.Mensaje)`, so it must have parameters... Can you just put your code in the question?